# Laravel 4 route NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to programming. I've been using codeigniter, and Laravel seemed a classy framework to learn. 
I have this routes:

```
Route::get('slider', 'AdminController@getSlider');
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@getSlider');
```

and my controller:

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

    public function getSlider(){
        return View::make('list', array('section' => 'slider_home'));
    }

}
```

"public/" works great. "public/slider" spits NotFoundHttpException.

If there is some data that i should add please tell me.

Thanks, and excuse my english.

**UPDATE:**

I got it wrong. The correct URL was "public/index.php/slider". Now I need to modify the .htacces to change that.

Comment: Route::get('public/slider', 'AdminController@getSlider');  should give you the result. or perhaps Route::get('/slider', 'AdminController@getSlider');.... also if you're needing to use public, you haven't configured laravel correctly unless you want to use the public in the extension.

Comment: Already tried but it keeps saying NotFoundHttpException. I've read ways to delete public from the URL but people say "insecurity" and stuff.

Comment: Try running this after you make the changes: $ composer dump-autoload -o or php composer.phar dump-autoload -o

Comment: Ok, got "Generating autoload files" and still NotFoundHttpException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Route :

```
Route::controller('','AdminController');
```

Controller :

```
class AdminController extends BaseController {

public function getIndex(){
    return View::make('list', array('section' => 'slider_home'));
 }
public function getSlider(){
    return View::make('list', array('section' => 'slider_home'));
 }
}
```

ok you can use public/ and public/slider

Comment: Did that, same problem.

Comment: yeah then its ur pretty url isnt done , here http://four.laravel.com/#pretty-urls